# How to structure a "many-to-many" relationship between nodes

Tags: nodes

I would like to have 2 node types, Sellers and Products. Each seller can have many products, and each product can have many sellers. Also, the relationship between Sellers and Products would need to contain a price.

What would be the best way to create that relationship, making it easy to list all the Products a seller sells on their page (with prices), as well as listing all of the Sellers selling a product on their page (with prices)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achieve by these two modules:
[Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) and [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference),

You can create Field Collection field (unlimited instances) to Product, the collection field (act like a wrapper) contains an Entity Reference field references to Seller, and a price field for that seller.

Some screenshot for you:

### [image]

### [image]

### [image]

[image]

Comment: I really love to see detailed answers like this one, great job (voted up)

Comment: Glad I can help. :)

Comment: gilder your example worked perfectly. But do you know a way to easily have the associated list of prices/products displayed on the Seller page?

Comment: gilder -> gilzero, stupid autocorrect :)

Comment: @itempo. Yes. You can use Views Attachment, or EVA module