# creating nodes with many to many relationship type with some fields?

Tags: nodes

This is in line with [How to structure a "many-to-many" relationship between nodes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36019/how-to-structure-a-many-to-many-relationship-between-nodes).

To keep things in line with the example from the linked thread, what if i was a book warehouse and i had a list of all my books but i want to allow each seller to name his own price and show that book in the seller's store view with only the price that he set?

How would I allow him to edit the info of his entry without having access to anyone else's entry? I am trying to avoid associating nodes from different content types like creating a node type seller's price and reference a book inside of it.

I thought about a combination of field collection, content access, and TAC to try to make each seller capable of entering and editing their own price field collection. While I thought that field collection would create a new collection for every user, this doesn't seem to work: All sellers end up editing the same collection.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the capabilities in the [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) module. With it you can relate a seller to a book, and attach a price field to the relationship.

> Relation is an API module and storage model for both simple and the
>   most complex relations between entities. The module can handle both
>   directional and symmetrical relations very well.
>
> Relations are entities and can therefore have fields. This makes
>   Relation the most flexible and powerful relation model out there.
>   (Still, using Relation with anything but the default SQL storage will
>   not work in most cases.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it looks like relation is in deed a good candidate for what i am trying to do. But is there a way to automate the relation creation? lets say when a book node is created the author selects a bunch of sellers from a term reference field and these sellers can automatically view the book in their list and add their own price and private text to it?

Comment: Set the default price to 0, and exclude zero prices from any view of the sellers' inventory. Give the seller a view of candidate books (price =  0) and if the seller sets a price, the item is removed from the candidate list and appears in the seller's inventory. Just set up your views accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Corresponding Entity References](https://www.drupal.org/project/cer) module.

> CER keeps reference fields in sync. If you have two entities that
>   refer to each other using Entity Reference (or some other kind of
>   reference field), it saves you the trouble of double-editing your
>   entities in order to have them point at each other. If entity Alice
>   references entity Bob, CER will make Bob reference Alice, and keep the
>   references up-to-date when either entity is updated or deleted.